# Mordell's Equation Solutions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I need to solve the equation $y^3 = x^2+5$, factoring we get $y^3 = (x+\sqrt{-5})(x-\sqrt{-5})$. Now considering the two ideals $(x\pm \sqrt{-5})$, I should show that they are coprime. Now I've been told that if I is prime and divides both of them, then it also divides $(2\sqrt{-5})$, ie $((x+\sqrt{-5})-(x-\sqrt{-5}))$, but why is it the case?
Once i can prove this, I can easily solve the equation.

Comment: If $a$ divides $b$ and $c$, then $b=ah$ and $c=ak$, so $b-c=a(h-k)$ is divisible by $a$.

Comment: great, but we're working with ideals

Comment: Does this really makes a difference?

Comment: I can see why the element divides it, but why does that imply that the ideal p divides (2sqrt(-5))? It's obvious if p is principal, but the ideal p might not be principal.

Comment: What's your definition of “$I$ divides $J$”?

Comment: There's an ideal K, such that J = I*K

Answer (score 1):

Keith Conrad has answered this with many examples in his article [Examples of Mordell's equation](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwiS3uPqpYPJAhXClnIKHS2rC7Q&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgradnumthy%2Fmordelleqn1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNExJsQ8bikneg2KeVVzvOH_vwlctQ&bvm=bv.106923889,d.bGg); e.g., compare with Theorem $2.2$ and $2.3$, which is, for example $y^2=x^3-5$ and $y^2=x^3-6$. Rewriting this by exchanging $x$ and $y$ we also obtain your case $y^3-5=x^2$. It has no integer solutions. The solution is elementary arguing modulo $4$.